# JInstaller::install: File '...' does not exist

Tags: joomla

My installer has been working until a few days ago, now I get:

```
JInstaller::install: File '/home/john/public_html/tmp/install_4c578c96e449f/com_mycomponent/admin/site/controllers' does not exist.
```

I checked the zip file and everything looks ok, I changed file contents but not the file structure at all since the time it was working.

ZIP STRUCTURE

```
com_mycomponent.xml
admin
     controllers
     ...rest of admin files
site
     controllers
     ...rest of site files
```

In fact the folder
`com_mycomponent/admin/site/controllers` does in face not exist, I don't know why it is looking for this folder.

Comment: @@JAX : have u resolved this issue... Because i am facing the same one right now... if u have resolved kindly post the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Please check your templateDetails.xml file. It must have mentioned about the folder name. Also, make sure if you want to add folder through template then that folder must not be empty

Answer (score 4):

I had the trouble that I had accidentally put a copy of the xml file inside the admin/ folder in addition to in the root folder. Maybe this happened to you too? Just delete it and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any backup files on the components folder or some where in the project folder delete it or cut it to some where else...

May be that solves your problem.

Because that solves for me.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by backup files?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. One of the file names, in templateDetails.xml had a typo. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it did not like my HTML file, so I deleted it from the XML.  When I checked the module installed and the HTML file was present.  I still included `<folder>html</folder` and also `<filename>index.html</filename>`